# Using buttons on layouts - Page curl Harism - Android

Tags: android, image, android-layout, bitmap, android-canvas

I am using the awesome lib provided by Harism in my app to implement the page curl effect. You can find it [here](http://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/) on github. I am using layouts instead of images on the curl page. But the layout buttons are not clickable. So, How can I make a layout with clickable buttons on the curl page?

Here is my layout instead of image code:

```
private int[] mBitmapIds = { R.layout.layout_1, R.layout.layout_2, R.layout.layout_3, R.layout.layout_4, R.layout.layout_5};

    @Override
    public int getPageCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    private Bitmap loadBitmap(int width, int height, int index) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View v = inflater.inflate(mBitmapIds[index],null);
        v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        v.draw(c);
        return b;
    }
```

I am beginner so please forgive me If i have made any mistakes.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey did you find a way out ??

Comment: It wont be clickable as its a bitmap,  we need to have a callback after the page has curled or loaded completely and then change the bitmap back to layout

Comment: how can we again change the bitmap back to layout